# Adding an email check constraint in APEX

Tags: oracle, email-validation, check-constraints, oracle-apex

I'm fairly new to Oracle and very new to APEX. I'm trying to add a constraint on a table to validate the email:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(CALLER_EMAIL, '[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}')
```

Now if I'm right this would work fine inside a `CONSTRAINT <name> CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(...))` however I get this (confusing) error when I attempt to save it:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

I think it is because the generated query contains `"CALLER_EMAIL"`:

```
alter table "CALL" add constraint
"CALL_EMAILFORMAT_CHK" check ( "CALLER_EMAIL" REGEXP_LIKE(CALLER_EMAIL, '[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be careful with this approach.  There are a large number of valid email addresses that may be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
alter table "CALL" add constraint
"CALL_EMAILFORMAT_CHK" check 
   ( REGEXP_LIKE(CALLER_EMAIL, '[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'));
```